# Whats going wrong in Implementation of this gaussian bernoulli RBM?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I have a problem in finding negdata value. In particular multiplying with sigma.  Could someone help in  representing this equation vishid*sigma*poshidstates + visbias in matlab.

```
 poshidstates=poshidprobs > rand(numcases,numhid);
 negdatapart=poshidstates*vishid'; %bsxfun(@rdivide,,sigmas));
 negdatapart2= (sigmas)*negdatapart';
 negdata= bsxfun(@plus,negdatapart2,repmat(visbiases,numcases,1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   vishid*sigma*poshidstates + visbias, equation can be  written in Matlab as below. The
```

error posted in question is due to the fact that it was not following elementwise multiplication.

```
  negdatapart= bsxfun(@times, poshidstates*vishid',sigmas);
  negdata= bsxfun(@plus,negdatapart,repmat(visbiases,numcases,1));
```